Vue3 project with no app service that fails on the "Deploy to Static Web Apps" with error on github: "deployment_token was not provided"
I have the following .yml setup (with keynames obscured):
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_<token name> }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/" # App source code path
          api_location: "api" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "dist" # Built app content directory - optional
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_<token name> }}
          action: "close"

The build always fails only with the "Build and Deploy" step, with the following error:
deployment_token provided was invalid.
An unknown exception has occurred

The workflow settings are:
api_location="api"
app_location="/"
output_location="dist"

There is currently no api, that isn't done yet, but the app builds and runs just fine on my computer with no errors.
I've tried to ask this question in Azure, but that environment is utterly contaminated with spam.
I've set the long token to my GPG token, which seems to be working fine for the push and commits. The other shorter one is supposed to be set automatically, but perhaps it's wrong, and I don't know how to change it.


deployment_token provided was invalid.
An unknown exception has occurred

This error throws when deployment token for the static web app is Invalid, as error says.
I also got the same error

This worked for me.
I have deployed default Vue app
To resolve this issue follow the steps:

Open you Static Web App -> Click on Manage deployment token and copy the token.



Open your GitHub repo and go to Settings -> Secretes and Variables -> Actions. Create an new secret. I have created a new Secret STATIC_APP_TOKEN_12345.


Note : There will be a pre created secret which is created while deploying the static web app.
If you want to Update it  you can update it with your . or you can create a new secret.
- Type you secret name and paste your token.




Update your .yml file with the new secret

azure-static-web-apps-lemon-smoke-04286be00.yml:
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.STATIC_APP_TOKEN_12345 }} # new Secret
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/" # App source code path
          api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "dist" # Built app content directory - optional
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.STATIC_APP_TOKEN_12345 }}
          action: "close"


Rerun the failed Job.
Deployment successful

OUTPUT:




can you add your yml file to this answer, it might help

@GeeWhizBang yml file is already added.

Unfortunately it still doesn't work, even with your yml format and my own secret key

@GeeWhizBang If the issue still persists, I would request you to raise an azure support request.

I finally got it to work by deleting all the configuration, the website, the group and starting over using the Azure vscode extension. This warned me that resource group could not be set to westUS, it had to be one of the other ones such as westUS2, because westUS doesn't support static sites. Which was probably the real problem all along.

Thanks for sharing your findings with community.
